# Tomcat based solr search, NoHttpResponseException, all jars added

Tags: java, solr, jar, classnotfoundexception

I use jsp to call the search algorithm to search through Solr and get the results.

My jsp page is like:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td>Your Search Results:</td>
            <td>
                <%
                    String queryKey = request.getParameter("jobSearch");
                    ArrayList<String> resultSet = SearchSolr.queryAll(queryKey);
                    out.println(resultSet);
                %>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The page continue to give me the error on the row of:

```
ArrayList<String> resultSet = SearchSolr.queryAll(queryKey);
```

Said that:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
```

The exception look like this:

```
    type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /Result.jsp at line 40

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Result.jsp at line 40

37:                 <td>
38:                     <%
39:                         String queryKey = request.getParameter("jobSearch");
40:                         ArrayList<String> resultSet = SearchSolr.queryAll(queryKey);
41:                         out.println(resultSet);
42:                     %>
43:                 </td>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException
    com.demoApp.solrJ.SearchSolr.queryAll(SearchSolr.java:16)
    org.apache.jsp.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    com.demoApp.solrJ.SearchSolr.queryAll(SearchSolr.java:16)
    org.apache.jsp.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I already imported all necessary jars including httpclient, httpcore, httpmime, httpclient-cache, etc.

The jars I imported are as follows: http://imageshack.com/a/img401/329/3we1.jpg

Comment: Can you dump your classpath jar's?

Comment: @AlexanderJardim you mean delete them all and add again?

Comment: No, dump your loaded classpath in something like pastebin.com, so we can analize it together.

Comment: @AlexanderJardim Sure! check the link I updated for a screenshot

Comment: Hm, can you find the class org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException inside any of the jar's?

Comment: @AlexanderJardim Yeah I found the NoHttpResponseException in httpcore-4.2.5

Comment: Can you try adding the jar to the tomcat lib folder and then restarting it ...

Comment: @AlexanderJardim Thank you so much to remind me this! It worked! The same problem happened once before when I was trying to start Solr through Tomcat!

Comment: it has to import all jars in project to tomcat's lib folder. Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has to import all jars in project to tomcat's lib folder. Solved!